# Before Staining... Do I need to sand my deck first? Or just chemical wash/pressure washer?

Tags: staining, decking, polish

We've been living in our new place for a few months now and now that we are more settled... I want to stay on top of maintaining the outdoor deck. But, I am unsure what's the material used for the deck (Merbau?) and when was the last polish.

Honestly, it does not look old but it is overly new either. Feels "dusty" when I walk around at times. Based on the picture, do you think it needs a resand? Or would chemical (deck cleaner) and pressure washer would be sufficient?
[image]

There's a small portion of the deck on the side that is not covered so it's obviously wearing out because of the weather exposure (see picture) below. Should just that portion be sanded?
[image]

Appreciate the opinions there guys :)

Comment: What product was used on the deck?

Answer (score 1):

Deck looks good to me.  I would not sand.  If you really want to restain, then just power wash, either with a mild detergent or plain water.